# a box appear next to an li element

Tags: jquery, css

i have a box :

```
#box1 { 
            height:100px;
            width:208px;  
            }
```

and a list

```
<li id="first"><strong>FIRST</strong>
</li>

<li id="second"><strong>SECOND</strong>
</li>

<li id="third"><strong>THIRD</strong>
</li>

<li id="fourth"><strong>FOURTH</strong>
</li>
```

with jquery i can make the box appear when i click on an li element...but i want the box to appear **next** to the element and not right down of the li... i just want to appear right next to it...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time grasping what you're asking. Could you clarify your intent and the problem you're having please?

Comment: thnx Vinay helped me with his answer below..im not good in english so i cant make the question as clear as i want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try ***display:inline-block;*** on the ***ul*** element. just a wild guess. would need more details.